# ubuntu server 20.04 restarts automatically frequently

Tags: linux, ubuntu, acpi

my ubuntu server 20.04 restarts automatically frequently, by reading `/var/log/messages`, have found errors:

```
ERST: Error Record Serialization Table (ERST) support is initialized.
RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
```

so i disabled acpi on grub, but number of cpu core only one, so i can't disable acpi, but if i don't disable acpi, ubuntu server 20.04 restarts automatically frequently. so what can i do? please help me

`/var/log/messages` error:

```
Jun 14 14:34:19 rdxc kernel: [    1.890242] ERST: Error Record Serialization Table (ERST) support is initialized.
Jun 14 14:34:19 rdxc kernel: [    2.235766] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
Jun 14 14:34:19 rdxc kernel: [    5.241309] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
Jun 14 14:34:20 rdxc udisksd[1211]: failed to load module mdraid: libbd_mdraid.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jun 14 14:34:20 rdxc udisksd[1211]: Failed to load the 'mdraid' libblockdev plugin
Jun 14 14:50:48 rdxc kernel: [    1.901010] ERST: Error Record Serialization Table (ERST) support is initialized.
Jun 14 14:50:48 rdxc kernel: [    2.239051] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
Jun 14 14:50:48 rdxc kernel: [    5.698169] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
Jun 14 14:50:48 rdxc udisksd[1189]: failed to load module mdraid: libbd_mdraid.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jun 14 14:50:48 rdxc udisksd[1189]: Failed to load the 'mdraid' libblockdev plugin
Jun 14 14:56:32 rdxc kernel: [    1.905311] ERST: Error Record Serialization Table (ERST) support is initialized.
Jun 14 14:56:32 rdxc kernel: [    2.239366] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
Jun 14 14:56:32 rdxc kernel: [    5.572594] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
Jun 14 14:56:32 rdxc udisksd[1209]: failed to load module mdraid: libbd_mdraid.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jun 14 14:56:32 rdxc udisksd[1209]: Failed to load the 'mdraid' libblockdev plugin
Jun 14 15:02:04 rdxc kernel: [    1.901658] ERST: Error Record Serialization Table (ERST) support is initialized.
Jun 14 15:02:04 rdxc kernel: [    2.239938] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
Jun 14 15:02:04 rdxc kernel: [    5.502321] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
Jun 14 15:02:04 rdxc udisksd[1203]: failed to load module mdraid: libbd_mdraid.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jun 14 15:02:04 rdxc udisksd[1203]: Failed to load the 'mdraid' libblockdev plugin
Jun 14 15:08:08 rdxc kernel: [    1.892493] ERST: Error Record Serialization Table (ERST) support is initialized.
Jun 14 15:08:08 rdxc kernel: [    2.171235] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
Jun 14 15:08:08 rdxc kernel: [    5.919836] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
Jun 14 15:08:09 rdxc udisksd[1158]: failed to load module mdraid: libbd_mdraid.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jun 14 15:08:09 rdxc udisksd[1158]: Failed to load the 'mdraid' libblockdev plugin
Binary file messages matches
```

dmesg error:

```
[    1.855507] ERST: Error Record Serialization Table (ERST) support is initialized.
[    2.141791] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[    7.295628] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

Comment: it's odd, those log messages seem to be from boot, then nothing for 16minutes, until the second "block", then 6 minutes between each subsequent block ... always the same 5 boot time messages, but nothing else - I don't think any of those messages relate to what happens to cause the reboot 16 or 6 minutes later - check `debug`, `kern.log` and `syslog`

Comment: Do you have any mdraid devices (`/dev/md...`)?

Comment: thanks for your replys, because my system was running 10 minutes that it will restart always.  syslog and kern.log is th same log.
Jun 14 17:26:26 rdxc kernel: [    2.126020] Key type dns_resolver registered
Jun 14 17:26:26 rdxc kernel: [    2.134974] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.

Comment: under /dev hasn't such /dev/md... devices

Comment: This is a stretch, but does this happen to be a virtual machine in a cloud, and the VM was launched by the cloud's orchestration system?  I've seen similar event patterns with servers launched in AWS by Cloudformation, due to a slight misconfiguration.

Comment: thanks for your replys, my server run on physic machine, isn't a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Does the server include any *watchdog* settings in the BIOS?

If such a hardware watchdog is enabled in BIOS, then you must either install the appropriate watchdog driver (which may be proprietary and only available for some distributions) or disable the watchdog.

Comment: i have no idea, how does confirm that has a harware watchdog is enabled?